# "2 duplicate symbols for architecture" when compiling package Rcpp, RcppProgress

Tags: c++, r, ld, rcpp

I suspect that this question arises from a misunderstanding of c++, but since I am using Rcpp I've tagged the question as such. I have created two functions, each in a separate .cpp file.

f1.cpp:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppProgress)]]
#include <progress.hpp>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector f1(int n)
{
    int i;
    Progress p(n, true);
    NumericVector x(n);

    for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
    {
      if (Progress::check_abort() )
        Rcpp::stop("Operation cancelled by interrupt.");

      p.increment(); // update progress

      x[i] = Rf_rnorm(0,1);
    }
    return x;
}
```

f2.cpp:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppProgress)]]
#include <progress.hpp>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector f2(int n)
{
    int i;
    Progress p(n, true);
    NumericVector x(n);

    for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
    {
      if (Progress::check_abort() )
        Rcpp::stop("Operation cancelled by interrupt.");

      p.increment(); // update progress

      x[i] = Rf_rgamma(1,1);
    }
    return x;
}
```

They both depend on RcppProgress. When I only compile my package using one of these files, I have no problem. But when I compile with both, I get the linker error:

```
duplicate symbol __Z14checkInterruptv in:
    f1.o
    f2.o
duplicate symbol __ZN8Progress18_monitor_singletonE in:
    f1.o
    f2.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I think this means I need to put the `#include <progress.hpp>` in a separate header file to be included from each of these cpp files, but I have tried that with no luck. I have also looked at other packages using Rcpp/RcppProgress, but it wasn't obvious what I should change.

Comment: Both your functions are called `f1`. Rename one of them.

Comment: You have a duplicate id (the same id `f1`) in both source files. Is that a copy/paste error or is that your **real** source code? If its your real code, why are you surprised you have a duplicate symbol link-time error?

Comment: Also, looking at the functions, you probably should combine them into one function and use a parameter to specify the distribution.

Comment: It was a copy paste error. `f1` in the second listing should be `f2`. I pasted from the wrong window.

Comment: @Roland: This is a toy problem meant to demonstrate the issue. My "real" code would not be amenable to combining the two functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not your fault. It's the fault of the RcppProgress authors. Their `progress.hpp` has

```
class Progress {
   // ...
private: // ===== INSTANCE VARIABLES
    static InterruptableProgressMonitor* _monitor_singleton;
};

InterruptableProgressMonitor* Progress::_monitor_singleton = 0;  // <-- this defines _monitor_singleton
```

Similarly, their `interrupts.hpp`, indirectly included, contains

```
bool checkInterrupt() {
    return (R_ToplevelExec(chkIntFn, NULL) == FALSE);
}
```

Both will cause an One Definition Rule violation when you include the header in two separate translation units (i.e., `.cpp` files), manifesting as the linker error you got. To resolve this issue, you will either need to rearrange your code somehow so that only one `.cpp` file includes `progress.hpp` (e.g., by combining the two files into a single one), or do some editing on their header files.

Comment: Thanks! I will contact the author of RcppProgress.

Comment: Or rearrange your code to only include RcppProgress.hpp in one of your files.